# Python Code to return column data in multiple feature classes and gdb's

Tags: arcpy, cursor

```
>>> import arcpy
... in_table = r"K:/MAPPING/PA/LEIDY/REPL/0188_18/MDL/GIS/MASTER/0188_18.gdb/DP_Centerline"
... with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, ["last_edited_date"]) as scursor:
...     for srow in scursor:
...         print srow[0]
... del srow, scursor
...
```

This works for DP_Centerline "last_edited_date" column and I am trying to PRINT "last_edited_date" across multiple feature classes within multiple geodatabases.

Comment: Are all you gdbs in the same folder? Do you have specific gdbs you can put in a python list? If not how do you identify your gdbs and how do you identify which feature classes within each gdb you wish to iterate?

Comment: You might be able to use arcpy.da.Walk. This can traverse multiple folders, subfolders,

Comment: Hello Emil, No the gdb's are not in the same folder. Here is the list of folders and gdb's I am trying to work with.                    K:\MAPPING\PA\LEIDY\LOOP\0183_18\MDL\GIS\MASTER\0183_18.gdb           K:\MAPPING\PA\LEIDY\LOOP\0116_18\MDL\GIS\MASTER\0116_18.gdb        K:\MAPPING\PA\LEIDY\REPL\0188_18\MDL\GIS\MASTER\0188_18.gdb    I Each gdb has roughly 60 feature classes that contain a "last_edited_date column in which I am trying to iterate by date range.